# Increasing memory limit in html5 video player

Tags: html, browser

I use html5 video player in my web page. When a user input a video file, then s/he can view his/her video. When file size in 25+ Mb, then works fine. But 70+ Mb browser console show a error as **NS_ERROR_OUT_OF_MEMORY:**.

How can i increase browser or player memory limit?

Comment: You mean you want the user to be able to view their local video files, that you somehow read with JS …? You most likely will not be able to increase the memory “limit” in that situation at all, because that’s browser internals, and not something a regular website _should_ have control over. (Because otherwise, I could easily create a website that just “freezes” the visitor’s browser and/or system, by requesting a large memory limit and then just writing random crap to RAM …)

Comment: thanks for your help...